# how to convert json.loads parse as string to dictionary python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The title may be misleading. I have a json file to load that looks like this :

```
{"parent": [
  {"venue": "SE", 
  "city": "some name", 
  "Rating": 2, 
  "location": {"x": 100.0, "y": 1.0}, 
  "pubMillis": 1581373546000}
  ], 
"startTime": "2020-02-12 00:00:00:000", 
"endTime": "2020-02-12 00:01:00:000"
}
{"parent": [
  {"venue": "PP", 
  "city": "some name 2", 
  "Rating": 2, 
  "location": {"x": 101.0, "y": 2.0}, 
  "pubMillis": 1581373546000}
  ], 
"startTime": "2020-02-12 00:00:00:000", 
"endTime": "2020-02-12 00:05:00:000"
}
```

Every `parent` key is separated by `\n` as shown.

I want to read this and this is my code :

```
with open('filename.json', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
records = json.loads(json.dumps(content))

print(type(records)) #return as str
```

If I write `records = json.loads(content)`, I will get the following error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 517)

Hence, `json.loads(json.dumps(content))` seems to work. However, I learn that converting `dumps` -> `loads` will return as `str` rather than `dict`. Therefore, I'm not able to access the items such as `records["parents"]["location"]` since they're in string.

So, how can I access items inside by converting `str` to `dict`?

Comment: The problem is **you don't have a json file**. What produced this? You should fix that

Comment: The line and column numbers in your error message indicate that your data file doesn't look like what you've posted. It looks like you've manually inserted a bunch of line breaks and indentation that aren't present in your real file.

Comment: Anyway, this is not a JSON file. The file might be [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/) (though what you've posted is not JSONL).

Comment: I `pprint` the json file to be more readable. @user2357112supportsMonica. In actual theyre in single line but separated by `\n`

Comment: If the file has one json 'dictionary' per line, then read it line by line, and apply `json.loads` to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the problem

it looks like either you have more than one son file, `{.....}` is one json

OR

those (`{.....}`) should be in an array... I have shown below the array method

```
a = '''{"parent": [
  {"venue": "SE", 
  "city": "some name", 
  "Rating": 2, 
  "location": {"x": 100.0, "y": 1.0}, 
  "pubMillis": 1581373546000}
  ], 
"startTime": "2020-02-12 00:00:00:000", 
"endTime": "2020-02-12 00:01:00:000"
}
{"parent": [
  {"venue": "PP", 
  "city": "some name 2", 
  "Rating": 2, 
  "location": {"x": 101.0, "y": 2.0}, 
  "pubMillis": 1581373546000}
  ], 
"startTime": "2020-02-12 00:00:00:000", 
"endTime": "2020-02-12 00:05:00:000"
}'''
a = [i.strip() if i.strip()!='}' else i.strip()+',' for i in a.split('\n') ]
a = '\n'.join(a)
a= '[\n'+a[:-1]+'\n]'
import json 
a=json.loads(a) 
print(a)
```

```
[{'endTime': '2020-02-12 00:01:00:000',
  'parent': [{'Rating': 2,
    'city': 'some name',
    'location': {'x': 100.0, 'y': 1.0},
    'pubMillis': 1581373546000,
    'venue': 'SE'}],
  'startTime': '2020-02-12 00:00:00:000'},
 {'endTime': '2020-02-12 00:05:00:000',
  'parent': [{'Rating': 2,
    'city': 'some name 2',
    'location': {'x': 101.0, 'y': 2.0},
    'pubMillis': 1581373546000,
    'venue': 'PP'}],
  'startTime': '2020-02-12 00:00:00:000'}]
```

this is how you will get the data

```
a=json.loads(a) 
#print(a)
print(a[0]['parent'][0]['location'])
```

```
{'x': 100.0, 'y': 1.0}
```

if you want to read files into memory

```
a = "".join([i for i in open('yourFileLocation','r').readlines()])
```

now you have `a` in memory as a multiline string

Comment: It works but in my case I have thousands of files like this. So I need to edit every file as an array first. Means, I need to read the file first and foremost... How can I do this?

Comment: You can read files into memory, perform the above operation! You can also read your file from { to} and process accordingly

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. Sorry. What do you mean by read files into memory?

Comment: Read files into memory as multiline strings

Comment: @xixi i have updated code how to read files, just update `yourFileLocation`

Comment: Thank you. but I'm receiving this error : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 1 (char 519)`, the delimiter I have is `\n` instead. It does not replace `\n` to `,`

Comment: I amended your code `a = ','.join(a)`. That was causing the error. Thanks!